# Integrate Paypal in Nextjs 14 and Typescript

Tags: next.js, paypal

PayPalButtons, PayPalScriptProvider work only in Sandbox not in 'Go Live

Everything worked fine with the Sandbox using PayPalButtons and PayPalScriptProvider. However, when going live, the PaypalButton only appears when I insert clientId='test', which keeps redirecting me to the Sandbox

Answer (score 0):

To switch from the sandbox to live environment:

- On the frontend, PayPalScriptProvider must be configured to load with a live client id from a [live PayPal application](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Fapplications%2F/live&intent=developer).
- The frontend's createOrder / onApprove functions must call a backend that itself uses a live client id and secret, and communicates with live PayPal API endpoints (no `sandbox.` in the domain names).